# Python for loop returns first value

Tags: python, for-loop

Background:  the code is supposed to reference a ticker symbol and the time of a trade, and then pull in the subsequent closing prices after the time of the trade (next_price_1m and next_price_2m)

Problem: when a ticker repeats, the next_price_1m and next_price_2m repeat from the prior call for that ticker, even though the time of the trade has changed.  My initial call to get barset is working, but only for the first instance of the ticker.

Example output:

```
symbol | transaction_time | next price 1m | next price 2m |  
 --------|------------------|---------------|---------------|-- 
  JPM    | 10:00 a.m.       | $90           | $91           |  
  SPY    | 10:25 a.m.       | $260          | $261          |  
  JPM    | 11:37 a.m.       | $90           | $91           |  
  AAPL   | 2:25 p.m.        | $330          | $335          |  
  JPM    | 3:02 p.m.        | $90           | $91           |
```

JPM should have different next_price_1m and next_price_2m on 2nd and 3rd calls.

Code:

```
trades_list = api.get_activities(date='2020-04-06')
data = []
for trade in trades_list:
  my_list_of_trade_order_ids = trade.order_id
  price = trade.price
  qty = trade.qty
  side = trade.side
  symbol = trade.symbol
  transaction_time = trade.transaction_time
  client_order_id = api.get_order(trade.order_id).client_order_id
  barset = api.get_barset(timeframe='minute',symbols=trade.symbol,limit=15,after=trade.transaction_time)
  df_bars = pd.DataFrame(barset)
  next_price_1m = df_bars.iat[0,0].c
  next_price_2m = df_bars.iat[1,0].c
  data.append({'price':price, 'qty':qty, 'side':side,'symbol':symbol,'transaction_time':transaction_time, 'client_order_id':client_order_id, 'next price 1m':next_price_1m,'next price 2m':next_price_2m})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that duplicates values, so `api.get_barset()` must be returning duplicates.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You've failed to provide a stand-alone example, and you neglected to do the expected values trace.  Insert strategic `print` statements to show the values.

Comment: The likely issue here is that whatever stack you're calling the API through appears to be caching a result that it shouldn't be caching. Could be the service itself, a proxy or whatever `api` is. It's also possible that `api` has functionality that allows you to clear cache or parameters that tell it to ignore cache, but you need to provide a more complete example for anyone here to know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.

The issue was that the 'after' parameter was looking for a timestamp in a different format than the timestamp format being provided with trade.transaction_time

Rather than providing an error, the API would ignore the time parameters, and just return the latest data.